# Problem with navigate to next detail Page with MasterDetailPage?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a problem, i changed Master Page after login. I want go next to new detail Page, but I can't navigate to next Page. I had error like `Master must not already have a parent` or work clear but master page goes back to the first initialization.
Code first inizialize:

```cs
 public MainPage()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      Master = new HamburgerMenu();
      Detail = new NavigationPage(new GroupListPage());
      App.MasterDetail = this;
}
```

Code change Maste Page:

```cs
App.MasterDetail.Master = new MenuPage();
```

and code when i want go next to diffrent detail page with save new master Page

```cs
Page oldMaster = App.MasterDetail.Master;
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage() {Master = oldMaster, Detail = new NavigationPage(new SecondPage()) });
```

Comment: You could try to set Master to null before change it to a new page.

Comment: typically with a MD page the Master page stays the same as the user navigates using the Detail.  You can wrap the Detail in a NavigationPage and use hierarchical navigation